# Audio Stream Problem In IOS

Tags: wordpress, server, html5, audio, ios

I’m using WordPress 5.6 and WordPress Internal Audio Player (HTML 5 Audio Player). Everything is OK on all major browsers, PC, Android - except iOS.

In iOS browsers (Safari, Firefox, etc) it turns to Live Broadcast with no Progress Bar, like on the image below:
[image]

And its not working well. It allways stops playing the music in the middle and also plays the music with noise in a way. It seems files are corrupted.

I think its happening because it tries to broadcast the Audio Live from my server, because when I use Audio with Link to another server (Audio Player URL Option), the audio player works well with progress bar.

Anyone know how can I figure out this problem ?
Maybe any improvement in WordPress or in server settings can solve this problem?